# How to Filter over Numbers? (Vuejs, API)

Tags: vue.js, web, filter, searchbar

I'm new to Programming and Vuejs. Here's my problem:
I created a Searchbar for my Website and `user.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchstring.toLowerCase())`works fine, but how can i search for numbers in my Searchbar?

Here is my HTML/TailwindCSS part for the SearchBar:  `<input type="text" v-model="searchstring" placeholder="Suche" class="border-0 border-b-2 border-gray-500 px-2 py-1 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500" />`

```
export default { 


  components: {
    TopNavbar,
  },
  

 name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      searchstring:"",
      apiurl: "https://MYAPI/api/users/",
      usersdata: [],
      noPicture: "https://MYAPI/userpictures/default-m.jpg",
      view: false,
      
    }
  } ,

  watch: {
    searchstring: function(newSearchstring) {
     console.log(newSearchstring)

    }
  
  },
  
  computed: {
    usersdata() {
    
      const compare = (a, b) => {
        if (a.title < b.title) return -1;
        if (a.title > b.title) return 1;
        return 0;

      };
      
    return this.usersdata
     .filter((user) => {
      return user.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchstring.toLowerCase()) || user.id.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchstring.toLowerCase())

     })
     
     .sort(compare);
    },
  },

   

  methods: {  



  
     async getdatafromapi() {
       const response = await fetch(this.apiurl);
       const data = await response.json();
       console.log(data)
       this.usersdata = data
      
      
     },

      },

    methodToRunOnSelected(option) {
      this.object = option;
    },



      
  
  async mounted() { 
    await this.getdatafromapi()

  }
  


}
```

Comment: Which version of VueJs are you using?  Also, please show more code.

Comment: I am using Vue 3.

Comment: IIRC, the original code contained a user.phone.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchstring.toLowerCase()) but the new code doesn't.  After restoring that code, I recommend adding a console.log(user.phone, this.searchstring) line immediately before the return statement.  Then look at the browser's console.

Comment: I tried it but i get an Error that user is not defined.  "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: user is not defined"